# Incorrect Syntax near '=' message 102 ,any ideas for this error?

Tags: sql-server

```sql
select name  ,surname,available_amount,

case 
     when name=credit_account  then amount = amount+available_amount 
     when name=debit_account   then amount = amount-available_amount 
     else amount
     
     end as available_balance
      
      from accounts_table,transaction_table;
```

Comment: `then amount = amount+available_amount` is a boolean expression; that can't go in your `THEN`. `CASE` is a expression, and it returns a scalar value, not a boolean result. Though I would *assume* you actually just don't need the `amount =` in the `WHEN`.

Comment: Start over. No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). You join two tables - no one but you knows which table contains the columns you reference. We might guess but we should not need to. And when you encounter an error, post the complete error message and not just what you think is important.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `name` is a nvarchar/varchar you're missing quotes around the value

eg.

```
when name='credit_account'
```

Also the syntax of the `then` part is wrong it should just be

```
then amount+available_amount
```